# trying to get administrative permission(without uac) in batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
goto check_Permissions

:check_Permissions
SET "C:\Users\BDAS\Desktop\check_admin=%~dp0"&SET "check_admin=%~dpf0"
net session >nul 2>nul & if errorlevel 1  check_admin "%~0" %*
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed. > res_txt.txt
) else (
    echo Failure: Current permissions inadequate. > res_txt.txt
)

pause
```

Comment: You can do that with a single opening line: ```@(%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Session 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.) || Echo Failure: Current permissions inadequate.) 1>"res_txt.txt"```. Please note however that your result file does not currently include a location, so if the script was run using the 'Run as administrator' option, the current directory will likely be `C:\Windows\System32`, which means your `res_txt.txt` file would be written to that location instead. I would advise therefore that you use a location which is the same in both scenarios.

Comment: i want to  start notepad.exe as administrator , but where i have to set the code

Comment: Your submitted code or question makes absolutely no mention of notepad.exe, or a need to start it elevated. I also do not see any real world use for 'Run'ning notepad.exe 'as administrator'. If you are not really using notepad.exe, why pretend otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Detecting elevation can be done more simply with `openfiles`:

```
openfiles > NUL 2>&1 && (
  echo Administrative permissions confirmed.
  exit /b 0
) else (
  echo Current permissions inadequate.
  exit /b 1
)
```

The full script to run notepad.exe with administrative privileges is here:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

REM Check admin mode, auto-elevate if required.
  openfiles > NUL 2>&1 || (
    REM Not elevated. Do it.
    echo createObject^("Shell.Application"^).shellExecute "%~dpnx0", "%*", "", "runas">"%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    goto :eof
  )
  del /s /q "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs" > NUL 2>&1
)

REM If here, then process is elevated. Otherwise, batch is already terminated and/or stuck in code above.

start "" notepad.exe
goto :eof
```

In no way you can bypass UAC, but by disabling it fully for the current account. If it was possible to do so, absolutely NO Windows machine connected to Internet would be virus-free since YEARS. But at least, the batch will handle automatically the elevation request, so if you forget to run it as Administrator, it will prompt you to allow elevation.